# Prevent XSS by preventing HTML tags in GET/POST

Tags: html, http, xss, middleware

Is it possible to prevent **XSS attack** simply be preventing any **HTML tag (encoded/not encoded)** in **GET/POST inputs**? Also, no (intentional) dynamic data from server side contains any HTML tag.

HTML tags can be prevented simply by a **middleware** that checks for if any html tag is presented in any **GET/POST** request.

All my **static strings are safe** and only dynamic strings are what i have to worry about, and **dynamic strings** either come from the **client (with GET/POST requests)** or come from the **database**, then if i can ensure that non of these characters **[", ', <, >, &]** are in any dynamic string coming from **client or from database**, will I be able to avoid XSS?

Comment: Not fully. Imagine something like this: `<script>var something = "<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>";</script>` Or something like this: `<img src="<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>" />` and a payload like `#" onload="doevilthings`.

Comment: What If I also prevent these characters: ", ', <, >, &

Comment: Depending on where the input might be reflected, and how bad the code is, even then it could be possible. Also, I would tend to think there are many places such characters would want to be allowed.

Comment: I do not need these characters to be allowed.

Comment: You have to either sanitize by javascript, or if it is disabled, sanitize it in the server

Comment: Yes. But if all my static strings are safe and only dynamic strings are what i have to worry about, and dynamic strings either come from the client (with GET/POST requests) or come from the database, then if i can ensure that non of these characters [", ', <, >, &] are in any dynamic string coming from client or from database, will I be able to avoid XSS?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you'd prevent [", ', <, >, &] one could inject bad code. It always depends on what you do with the data sent. Do you want to display it? If so, why not just using htmlspecialchars-equivalent, already existing, tested functions?

By only disallowing the characters stated above, you still could be infected depending on where you insert the data. Imagine the following:

```
<img src="...." <?=$_GET['data']; ?> />
```

By inserting *onclick=alert(document.cookie)* you can also execute code.

As I said, it depends on where you insert the data, but the best practice against XSS (and definitely all other potential attack vectors) is using **intense tested, well-known, already existing functions.**

In addition, this would also cause potential security issues:

```
<a href="<?=$_GET['data']; ?>">sometext</a>
```

...if you'd insert something like *javascript:alert(document.cookie)* or similar.

Comment: Can you let me know of any intense tested, well-known, already existing function which can properly sanitize attribute values
<a href = "<?php $_GET['sanitize_me']; ?>" >sometext</a>

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now! Thanks! I have now made a habit of properly escaping strings and also not echoing any dynamic data that could be potentially harmful in attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

## Assuming you're using **PHP**:

- Using MySQL after getting the input:

  ```
  $foo = $_POST['bar'];
  $safefoo = $mysqli_instance->real_escape_string($foo)
  ```

Safefoo will be a sanitized version of the variable

If you're not using mysql, but want to remove special characters

```
// Strip HTML Tags
$clear = strip_tags($des);
// Clean up things like &amp;
$clear = html_entity_decode($clear);
// Strip out any url-encoded stuff
$clear = urldecode($clear);
// Replace non-AlNum characters with space
$clear = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', ' ', $clear);
// Replace Multiple spaces with single space
$clear = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $clear);
// Trim the string of leading/trailing space
$clear = trim($clear);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid XSS and code injection (and still maintain data transparency) by properly *escaping* all the input data:

Pseudo-code:

```
// Pre-processing:
myData=readFromHttp("arg-name");

// ...Processing...
// Use myData only in user sections, not for composing SQL statements:
// SQL statements should be static, and apply dynamic data through placeholders.

// Post-processing: Compose an HTML result:
"<html>"+escapeHtml(myData)"</html>"
```

The `escapeHtml` function must perform these replacings in this order:

```
& --> &amp;
< --> &lt;
> --> &gt;
" --> &quot;
```

Again, you must use parameters to accept *data* from user, not *code*. There are certain regions in HTML when data is accepted:

```
<a title="data">...</a>
<strong>data</strong>
<p>data</p>
```

... but there are others where only code (or URLs) is accepted. These must be composed with **static** code:

```
<a href="code">...
<img src="code">...
<script src="code">...
<script>code</script>
```